# Calculate between two value of selected dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

How to calculate value from two selected drop down and show up in text box?

**And also i would like to calculate auto not buy click on button..**

Html code
Insurance :

```
<select class="form-control" name="insurance" onchange="calcVals()" id="insurance">
   <option disabled="" selected="" ></option>
   <option value="200">Yes</option>
   <option value="0">No </option>
</select>
```

Manpower:

```
<select class="form-control" name="manpower" id="manpower" onchange="calcVals()">
   <option disabled="" selected=""></option>
   <option value="150">1</option>
   <option value="300">2</option>
   <option value="450">3</option>
   <option value="600">4</option>
   <option value="750">5</option>
</select>
```

Textbox :

```
<input name="totalAmount" id="totalAmount" type="text"  readonly>
```

javascript:

```
    function calcVals() {
    var e = document.getElementById("manpower");
    var selFrst = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var f = document.getElementById("insurance");
    var selScnd = f.options[f.selectedIndex].text;

    var totalCal = selFrst + selScnd;
    document.getElementById("totalAmount").value = totalCal;
 }
```

Comment: `getElementById("insurance");` you have no such element

Comment: By the way, do you expect the output to be something like `No 1` or `No 2` ... `No 5` or `Yes1` or `Yes2` ... `Yes5` ?

Comment: forget to edit it, by the way the total was not + , it was showing "5Yes" @bravo

Comment: nope Something like 1 + 1 = "2"

Comment: So, you do want to display "No n" with a space or Yesn" without a space? (where n is 1 to 5)

Comment: 1 + 1? how do you expect 1 + 1?

Comment: var firstValue = document.getElementById("manpower").value;
var secondValue = document.getElementById("insurance").value;
var totalCal = firstValue + secondValue;
    document.getElementById("totalAmount").value = totalCal;

Comment: Value from insurance if select yes "200" and select "5" from the manpower so the total amount will be =" 205"

Comment: It is not a helpful question to the community and better to close this question. It is simple logic in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, add `id="insurance"` to the insurance select

Secondly, you want the value, if you want to add the values

```js
function calcVals() {
  var e = document.getElementById("manpower");
  var f = document.getElementById("insurance");
  var selFrst = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var selScnd = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value;

  var totalCal = +selFrst + +selScnd;
  document.getElementById("totalAmount").value = totalCal;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="insurance" id="insurance" onchange="calcVals()">
  <option disabled="" selected=""></option>
  <option value="200">Yes</option>
  <option value="0">No </option>
</select>

Manpower:

<select class="form-control" name="manpower" id="manpower" onchange="calcVals()">
  <option disabled="" selected=""></option>
  <option value="150">1</option>
  <option value="300">2</option>
  <option value="450">3</option>
  <option value="600">4</option>
  <option value="750">5</option>
</select>

Textbox :

<input name="totalAmount" id="totalAmount" type="text" readonly>
```

Comment: can u explain y have to put the "+" front of variable to calculate @bravo

Comment: that's short for parseFloat ... i.e. in most cases `+string` and `parseFloat(string)` are identical ... in this case, since all your values are easily coerced to Numbers, it's just a shorter form of code

Comment: @Bravo, + denotes ```parseInt``` or ```parseFloat```??

Comment: neither, but it's *like* parseFloat - in your case it doesn't matter (you do know that javascript only has Number type, not int or float?)

Answer (score 0):

there are no selecter of id "insurance" so you have to use "getElementsByName" instead of getElementsById.

please try this code:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="insurance" id="insurance" onchange="calcVals()">
  <option disabled="" selected=""></option>
  <option value="200">Yes</option>
  <option value="0">No </option>
</select>

Manpower:

<select class="form-control" name="manpower" id="manpower" onchange="calcVals()">
  <option disabled="" selected=""></option>
  <option value="150">1</option>
  <option value="300">2</option>
  <option value="450">3</option>
  <option value="600">4</option>
  <option value="750">5</option>
</select>

Textbox :

<input name="totalAmount" id="totalAmount" type="text" readonly>

<script>
function calcVals() {
    var e = document.getElementById("manpower");
    var selFrst = e[0].value;
    var f = document.getElementsByName("insurance");
    var selScnd = f[0].value;

    var totalCal = parseInt(selFrst) + parseInt(selScnd);
    document.getElementById("totalAmount").value = totalCal;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList` - so, your code is equally wrong

Comment: now you're adding one dropdowns text to another dropdowns value .... :p

Comment: really? so you do realise the manpower values are 150, 300, 450, 600 and 750 ... not 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: yes, @balamurugana has not specify nothing about value or text. so i do prefer value instead of text....

Comment: `i do prefer value instead of text` yet ... you use text

Comment: @Bravo that is my mistake, thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below you are missing somethings and we have to use parseInt to convert string to integer.

```js
function calcVals() {
    var e = document.getElementById("manpower");
    var selFrst = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var f = document.getElementById("insurance");
    var selScnd = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value;

    var totalCal = parseInt(selFrst) + parseInt(selScnd);
    document.getElementById("totalAmount").value = totalCal;
 }
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="insurance" id="insurance" onchange="calcVals()">
   <option disabled="" selected="" ></option>
   <option value="200">Yes</option>
   <option value="0">No </option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="manpower" id="manpower" onchange="calcVals()">
   <option disabled="" selected=""></option>
   <option value="150">1</option>
   <option value="300">2</option>
   <option value="450">3</option>
   <option value="600">4</option>
   <option value="750">5</option>
</select>

<input name="totalAmount" id="totalAmount" type="text"  readonly>
```